# Finding duplicate values occurring consecutively

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 40,000 rows of numbers, and all the numbers are sorted in sequence.

I want to pick up the numbers with duplicate values that occur consecutively. How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: What do you mean by "pick up"? Do you want them highlighted? Listed somewhere else on the sheet?

Comment: If the numbers are sorted in order then any duplicates are going to be adjacent, which simplifies the problem to one of "picking up" duplicate values. Are there other requirements to the question?

Comment: Dang!  I was reading the snippet on the home page.... immediately thought `uniq -d`... but then it says __Excel__... awwww, oh well.  But the solution given by @Wishwas will work.  Of course, so would 'export to csv, `sort myfile.csv | uniq -d > newfile.csv`, import to Excel'. Taa Daa!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a column called count to the right of whatever column you would like to identify your duplicates. Populate the count column cells with 1.
2. Select both columns and Insert a PivotTable.
3. Add the column with possible duplicates to Row Labels, and add your count column to Values.
4. Click the cell beneath the header cell "Count of Count" if your Count column was named Count, then under PivotTable Tools->Options, select sort Z->A to see the rows that have counts greater than 1. These are your duplicate rows and then number of duplicates.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, as they can become useless if the linked site changes. Be sure to include a synopsis of the relevant information from the link to make sure your answer will remain helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now I have revised the answer.